# How to start a first setup activity only one time

Tags: android, android-activity, startup

I'm currently programming an app which Shows a first Setup activity.

How can I let this FirstSetup.class activity be started only for the first time. At the end of the Setup, there is a button FinishSetupButton which could for example set a value 1 that says to the MainActivity not to Show the first Setup again.

How is that possible?

Comment: use shared preferences

Comment: check the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Ok, I understood that. But how can I make an If command in the MainActivity.Java that Looks for "StartFirstSetup" = 0 then startActivity (...) else if "StartFirstSetup" = 1 then return true;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do: check for a certain value in SharedPreferences every time the app starts. If the value doesn’t exist, this is the first time running an app - do what needs doing then save the value to SharedPreferences. If the value is there, it means this isn't the first time app is running. When app is uninstalled, this value will get removed from SharedPreferences, just FYI. Code below needs to be in an Activity.

```
static final String KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME =  "com.<your_app_name>.first_time";
static final String KEY =  "com.<your_app_name>";
```

...

```
public boolean isFirstTime(){
        return getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, true);
    }
```

...

this is how you would save this to SharedPreferences:

```
getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, false).commit();
```

Comment: java: non-static method getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,int) cannot be referenced from a static context is the error I get when I paste this into my MainActivity :/

Comment: Updated isFirstTime() method signature to make it not static. If you use SharedPreferences more then once, you might want to create a static SharedPreference variable in your main activity so you can reference it.

Comment: How can I do that? (Update the isfirstTime method)?

Comment: To make the example i provided work, copy-paste the method isFirstTime() from above as i have already updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I removed the static and put isFirstTime() in the onCreate, but nothing happens when I start the app. Must I put more code anywhere?

Comment: yes- now you must decide what to do if it is the first time using the app! like, if it IS the first time, start one activity and save to Shared Prefs, if it is NOT the first time, start another activity. Remember, this will ONLY WORK ONCE, so if you want it to be the FIRST TIME AGAIN, reinstall the app on your phone.

Comment: This is just a check to see if the app was ever started on the phone. It will not start any activities. I would start the app on your main activity, perform this check, and if this check returns TRUE, i'd rerout to your Setup Activity before showing the Main activity itself.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm planning to do. But which code do I have to enter? I thought at that:

if (...) = true then startActivity(new Intent(this, SetupActivity.class));
else if return false;

How should it be?

Comment: Look, this is something you have to figure out yourself. I use code that is almost identical to this to figure out if app has ever started on the phone and it works well. Figuring out what to do with this check is outside the scope of this question. If you need more help, ask another question detailing where you are having trouble and provide sample code. Also keep in mind that this check will only return TRUE ONCE PER APP INSTALLATION (as designed). Compiling code and updating the app (normal part of the dev) wont work twice! Also if you ended up using this, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a control activity that chooses the layout to display or the activity to run based on that value you saved.

For store options you can look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and choose the best approach for your case.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide me the code I would Need?

Answer (score 1):

I would use SharedPreferences to store that data:

```
    public static void setSettingsDone(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourPref", 0);
    final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("AlreadySetPref", true);
    editor.commit();
}

public static boolean isAlreadySet(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourPref", 0);
    return prefs.getBoolean("AlreadySetPref", false);
}
```

In the previous activity, I would call the second method. If false is returned, then the user hasn't already set up sot I'll launch the Settings activity, calling the first methodd at the end, otherwise, I'll launch the MainActivity...